# MPG Dataset UCI Repository

Tags: regression, self-study

I want to use this [dataset](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall00/G22.3033-001/weka/weka-3-0-2/data/auto-mpg.arff) for my regression project.

Does anybody know in what units is the variable *weight*? Pounds or kilos?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the data were originally provided from StatLib from where Quinlan and UCI obtained it. And StatLib has the description from the 1983 ASA Data Exposition where the data were used: http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/cars.desc

This says:

> There are 406 observations on the following 8 variables: MPG (miles
>   per gallon), # cylinders, engine displacement (cu. inches),
>   horsepower, vehicle weight (lbs.), time to accelerate from 0 to 60 mph
>   (sec.), model year (modulo 100), and origin of car (1. American, 2.
>   European,
>   3. Japanese). These data appear on seven pages. Also provided are the car labels (types) in the same order as the 8 variables on seven
>   separate pages. Missing data values are marked by series of question
>   marks.

So the answer to your question appears to be "lbs". Note also that 8 observations with missing response are deleted in the UCI version (leading to 398 instead of 406 observations).

Comment: Thanks! What does mean modulo 100? I suppose the model year variable means the year of the production of the particular car, am I right?

Comment: "modulo 100" means "remainder on dividing by 100". Something like `mod(1974, 100)` yields 74 in many languages. It's arguably an abuse of mathematical terminology as the modulus is one of the arguments, not the name for the result, but if so the abuse goes back to FORTRAN in the 1950s at least.

Comment: Modulo is the remainder after division, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation. For this data set, it's the mathematical way to say: years minus 1900 because all of the cars will have been built in the 20th century.

Comment: +1. The units of horsepower are, naturally, number of horses.

Comment: Now I see, never heard of that term modulo before :o Thanks!

Comment: And in case you want to work with the car name: This contains quite a few spelling mistakes such as chevroelt, maxda, toyouta, and vokswagen.

Comment: Essential question about the dataset regarding the variable *model year*. The *mpg* variable is for the cars as they were manufactured, or in the year 1983, as they were already used? Does anybody have an idea?

I mean, are we talking here about a fuel consumption for brand new cars which were manufactured during that time period from 1970-1983?

Comment: The most detailed description I could find is the one on StatLib which doesn't explain this aspect as far as I can see. I would suspect that the cars where new when the _mpg_ variable was assessed but that's just my personal guess.